# Can I authenticate a user in react without making a backend api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, authentication

I am building an app for a single user, and i don't want to build backend for it. How can I protect a route with help of authentication using state?
i dont want it to be secure. wondering if there is any way to prevent a route from loading based on a username and password

Comment: You cannot. Anything on the front end can be directly modified.

Comment: You can use a flag variable and can decide what you want to render and what you don't want but this is not how authentication works. For proper authentication you have to use some backend API.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you can't.
Authentication requires a backend API because it initiates what is called a session between the user and the API they are trying to access.
The frontend can always be manipulated, even if you code it in react and the people that use your website get some jibberish code, they can still manipulate it and change the state.
What you might be trying to do is protecting the website with a password. That, you can do, but as I mentioned above, it can be manipulated and people with a bit of knowledge can easily get the password from the state or wherever you save it.

Comment: i dont want it to be secure. wondering if there is any way to prevent a router from loading based on a username and password

Answer (score 0):

store your user details in local or session storage while login. then re-use it whenever you want. But this is not a good way its an a temporary way.